# How to call a view in voyager?

Tags: laravel

Im having issue to return a view in voyager.

This is inside my controller(App/Http/Controllers/TestController.php):

```
public function showGraph() 
{
    $users = DB::select('SELECT * FROM whmcs_clients_invoices');
    return view('index', ["users"=>$users]);
}
```

From the above code, the index view is actually inside the voyager. (vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/index.blade.php)

This is inside my route(routes/web.php).
// WHMCS Client Paths

```
Route::get('/admin', 'TestController@showGraph');
```

The issue now is "View [index] not found."

Can i know how to put the path correctly so that the function can work?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `view('voyager::index', ...)` ?

Comment: can i know the difference between voyager.index and voyager::index?

Comment: `voyager::` is a 'namespace' when it comes to views, the voyager service provider namespaces its views .... `voyager.index` would be looking for a 'index' view in a folder named 'voyager'